# Is there a way to stop Polars from word-wrapping column values?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, configuration, display, python-polars

When displaying a Polars df in a jupyter notebook, is there a way to prevent it from word-wrapping the column values? I've already set the string length in the Config parameters, but it hasn't helped and would prefer scrolling right more so my rows are more compact.

Comment: Have you tried using [`pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_width_chars.html)?

Comment: Just tried it and the strings still wrap.

Comment: A screenshot would really help understand your problem here

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars(width)`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_width_chars.html#polars.Config.set_tbl_width_chars) will not yield the desired behaviour.

**Solution:**
Try using the [`pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(n)`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths.html#polars.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths) function.

Setting `n` to a reasonable large number should display columns, that have a width between the longest string present in your displayed column and your set `n`.

[Here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/config.html), you will find additional information about the Config parameter of Polars.

Comment: Tried this, I think it's something with the Jupyter or browser formatting :(